# How to validate varied options via SWITCH based on user type in Selenium(C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, switch-statement, nunit

I am using - **Selenium(C#)** on **NUnit** framework and I am trying to validate a condition in my test that presents the user with varied options based on the user who has logged in(as explained below) -

1. **User1** -- *Personal Account* and *Business Account*
2. **User2** -- *Personal Account*, *Business Account* and *Retail Account*
3. **User3** -- *Business Account*, *Wholesale Account*, *Retail Account* and *Personal Account*

The code which I want to test is something like this -->

```
<div class="ng-star-inserted">
<!----><div class="row ng-star-inserted">
<div class="col-md-12">
<button class="btn w-btn-teleport-alt" id="account-type-btn-{idx}" 
type="button">
Retail Account
</button>
</div>
</div><div class="row ng-star-inserted">
<div class="col-md-12">
<button class="btn w-btn-teleport-alt" id="account-type-btn-{idx}" 
type="button">
Business Account
</button>
</div>
</div><div class="row ng-star-inserted">
<div class="col-md-12">
<button class="btn w-btn-teleport-alt" id="account-type-btn-{idx}" 
type="button">
Consumer Account 
</button>
</div>
</div><div class="row ng-star-inserted">
<div class="col-md-12">
<button class="btn w-btn-teleport-alt" id="account-type-btn-{idx}" 
type="button">
Wholesale Account
</button>
</div>
</div><div class="row ng-star-inserted">     
<div class="col-md-12">
<button class="btn w-btn-teleport-alt" id="account-type-btn-{idx}" 
type="button">
General Account
</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to validate this, so that depending on the **User** logged (driven by app.config) I should be able to validate the correct buttons present.

Is **SWITCH** the best way to validate this? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends how You switch statment will be implemented, I actually don't see a reason why not to use SWITCH. 
That being sed, without switch:

Depends of how Your automated solution is made but I quickly made an example in my solution (I’m using https://bitbucket.org/mk_meros/webautomation/wiki/Home as a framework for selenium)

In my solution I would do something like this:

Xpath: //button[text()='{0}']

```
    [When(@"I can see buttons:")]
    [Then(@"I can see buttons:")]
    public void ICanSeeButtons(Table table)
    {
        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            var buttonValue = row["buttons"];
            var field = this.Page.ButtonByText.With(buttonValue);
            field.Assert.Is.Displayed();
        }
    }
```

This solution would be generic, but it require to have three tests each for diffrent user. Also I would recomend to check NotDisplayed in the same test.